# Regarding Udemy Course - connect to Database with OOP

Tags: php, oop

in this course they build a class with a function of connect like this

```
private function connect(){
    $this->connection = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);

    if(!$this->connection){
        $this->error = "Connection Failed: ".$this->connection->connect_error;
        return false;
    }
```

And they build the function select like this

```
   public function select($query){
        $result = $this->connection->query($query) or die();
     }
```

I have never seen such construct with $this->...->....
Furthermore, the if-error in function one doesn't work an I gave replaced it with

```
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());}
```

and it works fine.

What is the correct way. Thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? `Warning 
The mysqli->connect_error property only works properly as of PHP versions 5.2.9 and 5.3.0. Use the mysqli_connect_error() function if compatibility with earlier PHP versions is required.`

Comment: Tutorials are fine, but use them while looking at the manual as well.

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? I'm guessing you just forgot to output `$this->error` (`echo $this->error;`) so you're not seeing the error message.

Comment: Hello HPierce, no I didn't forget it.